# PHP script doesn't run anymore

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that I use it like a cient to connect to a Java server with MySql. It worked yersterday, but today doesn't do anything anymore.
Anyone experienced this ? What could the problem be ?

edit: when i run it from command line, it doesnt output anything:

```
C:\Users\astan>"c:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.exe" c:\Users\astan\Downloa
ds\workspace\workspace\VR\src\test\php\VR.php

C:\Users\astan>
```

edit 2:

```
include('common.inc.php');

    echo "Videoraptor Client\n";

    // Maximum number of requests the client will handle before exiting.
    // (0 = unlimited)
    $VR_MAX_REQUESTS = 0;

    if (count($_SERVER['argv']) >= 2) {
        $VRSERVER['url'] = $_SERVER['argv'][1];
        if (count($_SERVER['argv']) >= 3)
            $VR_MAX_REQUESTS = $_SERVER['argv'][2];
    }
    echo "Server: ".$VRSERVER['url']."\n";
    echo "Max requests: $VR_MAX_REQUESTS\n\n";
```

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question.

Comment: Completely impossible to answer without more detail.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say it "doesn't run"? No errors, nothing on screen?

Comment: yes, it doesnt output nothing

Comment: I guess that yesterday's date is hard coded in code to proceed process. I cant say anything else with current details.

Comment: Only problem i see here is your question. Java and Php are fine doing.

Comment: @vBx if it "doesnt output nothing", it must output something? If you mean it doesn't output anything consider debugging your code.

Comment: Of course they are, I am just wondering why a script would not work the next day, my question is very good, i run it, and it doesnt do nothing. What info should I give ?

Comment: @Raoul: i dont know php, i just need to use this script, yersterday when i tets it, it will always say an error if it doesnt connect to the server, or something, but today nothing, blank

Comment: @ Karolis: where should i see this error logs ?

Comment: @vBx You give us no idea what this script does, just that it doesn't work. Honestly how are we supposed help you give we have no idea what this script is supposed to do?

Comment: I posted some code, to see that it should print something at the begining at least no ?

Comment: What's in include('common.inc.php')?

Comment: the path to php and to the server

Comment: could this be a probem with mysql ? I reinstalled but still doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things you can do:

- Check the logs.
- Add trace messages to your app so you see what's going on.
- Run it in a debugger.